# JavaScript: How to detect if an HTML checkbox was selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I:

1. detect if an HTML checkbox has be clicked/selected?
2. retrieve which checkbox(es) have been selected?

Example code:

```
<FORM ACTION="...">
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX VALUE="1">1 bedroom<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX VALUE="2">2 bedrooms<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX VALUE="3">3 bedrooms<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX VALUE="4+">4+ bedrooms<P>
</FORM>
```

Meaning,

1. if the web user selects "1 bedroom", I want an event to fire to inform me the user selected "1 bedroom".
2. As you can see, a user can select multiple checkboxes. For example, they might want to see homes that have either "1 bedroom" or "2 bedrooms". So they would selected both checkboxes. How do I retrieve the checkbox values when multiple checkboxes have been selected?

In case it helps, I would be open to using JQuery to simplify this.

Answer (score 12):

jQuery to the rescue! (since you tagged it as such):

```
$('input:checkbox[name=bedrooms]').click(function() {
  var values = $('input:checkbox[name=bedrooms]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get();

  // do something with values array
})
```

(make sure to add a `name="bedrooms"` attribute in the html for your checkboxes; you'll need them when submitting the form anyway, in order to retrieve them on the server).

I've used a few pseudo-selectors:

- [`"input:checkbox"`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox) finds all the input checkboxes on the page
- [`"[name=bedrooms]"`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue) finds all the elements with attribute `name="bedrooms"`
- [`":checked"`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) finds all the elements with attribute `checked=true`

Combine them as `"input:checkbox[name=bedrooms]:checked"` and jQuery gives you all the checked checkboxes.

For each one I [pluck out their `value` attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map) into an array you can simply iterate over and do what you wish.

**Edit**

You can optimize this code to save a reference to your checkboxes instead of telling jQuery to go fetch them all everytime there's a click:

```
var $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox[name=bedrooms]');
$checkboxes.click(function() {
  var values = $checkboxes
    .filter(function() { return this.checked })
    .map(function() { return this.value })
    .get();

  // do something with values array
})
```

In this sample I've saved the checkboxes into var `$checkboxes`. On click of any checkbox, instead of going back to the DOM to grab the checked ones, we simply [filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter) `$checkboxes` down to only the checkboxes that are checked, and for each one [pluck out the `value` attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map) into an array. The `get()` is just an obscure requirement to convert the "jQueryized" array to a regular JavaScript Array.

Comment: Pitfall is that it would collect EVERY checkbox in your document. What if he has more checkboxes than only for bedrooms?

Comment: Oh, the get(0) only returns 1st element of the map .. Not the raw array.

Comment: @BalusC: "He" has provided an example of a bunch of checkboxes in a form. That's what the answer is tailored to. If "he" had specific css `class`es, `name`s, or a container then it would have been remiss to exclude them.

Comment: @BalusC: on second thought, what good is a checkbox without a `name` attribute? Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

1) Use the onclick attribute.

2) You could give them each the same name and use `$('input[name=yourname]:checked')` to get them all.

[Edit] as requested, here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(init);

            function init() {
                // Add onclick function to every checkbox with name "bedrooms".
                $('input[name=bedrooms]').click(showCheckedValues);
            }

            function showCheckedValues() {
                // Gather all values of checked checkboxes with name "bedrooms".
                var checked = $('input[name=bedrooms]:checked').map(function() {
                    return this.value;
                }).get();
                alert(checked);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="bedrooms" value="1">1 bedroom<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="bedrooms" value="2">2 bedroom<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="bedrooms" value="3">3 bedroom<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="bedrooms" value="4+">4+ bedroom<br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BalusC, would you mind elaborating some by showing some code. I'm very excited at your response but am a little unclear exactly how it would work.

Comment: Funny, syntax highlighting went mad in the 2nd <script> and I can't figure how that's been caused.

Comment: what happen if the <input type="checkbox" name...> is generated dynamically. So when document.ready() fire up, it cant register the click event to the checkbox since the checkbox is not there yet. How can we solve this problem?

Comment: @Harry Pham: replace `jQueryElement.click(function ...)` by `jQueryElement.live('click', function ...)`. API doc: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

```
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" 
       value="My Check Box"> Check Me
  </form>

   <a href="#" onClick="window.alert(document.myForm.myCheck.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No');">Am I Checked?</a>
```

This is from a textbook called JavaScript in 10 Easy Steps or Less by Arman Danesh - so i'd assume this works. hope it helps

Comment: `document.myForm.myCheck.checked` is the bit relevant to the question

Comment: oh. well i thought it might help to see where it all went. sorry for any confusion

Comment: no worries, I just thought to highlight what was the most helpful part of your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign names and/or IDs to your checkbox elements so that you can distinguish them in code. Then, using jQuery, add events with `bind` if you want to handle the check/uncheck state changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use IDs on your checkbox.

```
<FORM ACTION="...">
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX id="c1" VALUE="1">1 bedroom<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX id="c2" VALUE="2">2 bedrooms<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX id="c3" VALUE="3">3 bedrooms<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX id="c4" VALUE="4+">4+ bedrooms<P>
</FORM>



$('c1').checked // returns whether the 1 bedroom checkbox is true or false
```

Comment: $('c1').checked is a check to see if it has been selected. I need an Event to fire to inform me that the check box has been selected. How do I create the event to fire if the check box has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .checked property on a checkbox to retrieve whether a checkbox has been checked. To fire an event when a checkbox is checked, you can use the click event in jquery. Something like the below would work to list all checkboxes on the page that have been checked.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    // if you want information about the specific checkbox that was clicked        
    alert("checkbox name : " + $(this).name + " | checked : " + $(this).checked);

    // if you want to do something with ALL the checkboxes on click. 
    $.each($["input[type='checkbox']", function(i, checkEl) {
       // put any of your code to do something with the checkboxes here.
       alert("checkbox name : " + checkEl.name + " | checked : " + checkEl.checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use events to see if a checkbox was selected (onChange).  You can read more about it at the [Essential Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Essential_Javascript_--_A_Javascript_Tutorial) tutorial (see the section entitled: **Javascript is an Event Driven Language**)

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
...<input type="checkbox">...
```

1. detect if an HTML checkbox has be clicked/selected?

a: using jQuery 1.7+:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").click(function () {
        console.log($(this)[0].checked);
    });      
});
```

1. retrieve which checkbox(es) have been selected?

a: again using jQuery 1.7+:

```
console.log($('input:checked'));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

If you do not want to use JQuery you could always use

```
document.GetElementById("cbxCheckbox1");
```